# Calling register_shutdown_function inside a class

Tags: php, oop, error-handling

I am trying to log the errors using **register_shutdown_function** and **set_error_handler** functions. I am using the following class file for the same. However it does not work.

```
 <?php
//Logs.php
class MyLogs
{

    public function __construct() 
    {
        register_shutdown_function(array($this, 'shutdownHandler'));
        set_error_handler(array($this, 'errorHandler'));
    }

    private function errorHandler($error_level, $error_message, $error_file, $error_line, $error_context)
    {
        $error = "lvl: " . $error_level . " | msg:" . $error_message . " | file:" . $error_file . " | ln:" . $error_line;

        switch ($error_level) {
            case E_ERROR:
            case E_CORE_ERROR:
            case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
            case E_PARSE:
            case E_USER_ERROR:
                $this->logMe($error, "fatal");
                break;
            case E_USER_ERROR:
            case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
                $this->logMe($error, "error");
                break;
            case E_WARNING:
            case E_CORE_WARNING:
            case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
            case E_USER_WARNING:
                $this->logMe($error, "warn");
                break;
            case E_NOTICE:
            case E_USER_NOTICE:
                $this->logMe($error, "info");
                break;
            case E_STRICT:
                $this->logMe($error, "debug");
                break;
            default:
                $this->logMe($error, "warn");
        }
    }

    private function shutdownHandler() //will be called when php script ends.
    {
      $lasterror = error_get_last();

      echo "Level: " . $lasterror;
      switch ($lasterror['type'])
      {
          case E_ERROR:
          case E_CORE_ERROR:
          case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
          case E_USER_ERROR:
          case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
          case E_CORE_WARNING:
          case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
          case E_PARSE:
              $error = "[SHUTDOWN] lvl:" . $lasterror['type'] . " | msg:" . $lasterror['message'] . " | file:" . $lasterror['file'] . " | ln:" . $lasterror['line'];
              $this->logMe($error, "fatal");
      }
    }

    private function logMe($error, $errlvl)
    {
       echo 'Error No: ' . $error . ' <BR> Error Level: ' .$errlvl;
    }
}
```

..

```
<?php
// Index.php
include "Logs.php"

new MyLogs();
echo $b; //this should generate a notice error since $b does not exits...
```

However, if I do not use a class but just functions, they work fine...can someone please tell me whats wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @sectus answer below seems like a fairly straightforward answer.  If it works you should select it as the accepted answer yes?

Answer (score 9):

You should set properly your error settings. For example

```
ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

After this you would find your error: your `shutdownHandler` and `errorHandler` have to be public.